# Image viewer with two images zooming at same time

Tags: ubuntu, image-viewer

I am looking for an image viewer which can load two images of the same size at the same time and when I zoom in one, the same region is being displayed on the other one. Any idea, for such software on Ubuntu or online?

Answer (score 1):

I talked with a friend and found a solution:

1. Save the images as a multi-frame TIFF file
2. Open it with the 3D Slicer software
3. 3D Slicer will view each image as different slice in a volume. This will allow you to compare between the two easily.